# Technique to solve $\int{(\frac{d(\frac{u}{v})}{dx})dx}$

Tags: integration

I recently stumbled upon this:
$$\int{\frac{x\cos(\theta)+1}{(x^2+2x\cos(\theta)+1)^{3/2}}dx}$$

I immediately knew from the options that this was the derivative of some $\frac{u}{v}$ form. But I couldn't see myself settling to a substitution for these types.

Is there a standard substitution that I can apply? How can I cleverly trace it back to $\int{d(\frac{u}{v})}$?

Comment: Add and subtract $x^2+x\cos\theta$ from the numerator

Answer (score 5):

The solution goes like this

Let $k=\cos\theta$

$$\int\frac{\left(kx+1\right)dx}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)dx}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{\left(x\right)\left(x+k\right)dx}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{d\left(x\right)}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{x\cdot d\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot dx\ +\ x\cdot d\left(\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{x}{\left(x^{2}+2kx+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+C$$

If you can figure out that the integral is of the form $\frac uv$ , then try manipulating it as a product rule. Every function $\frac uv$ can be written as $u\cdot\frac1v$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where have you applied the "product rule"? It would be helpful if you could provide a generalization since this came out to be easily manipulative( into linear + quadratic form,a standard one for $\int{\frac{dx}{\text{quadratic}}}$)

Comment: It isnt a dx/quadratic.I have written it as the derivative of product of two functions. The product rule is d(uv)=vdu+udv...

Comment: @DatBoi I haven't seen any generalization to solve such problems yet. You have to manipulate the integral to identify that it is of u/v form. This was just a demonstration that manipulating it into a u.(1/v) form is much efficient that manipulating it into (vdu-udv)/(v^2)... The thought process develops with practice

Comment: @DatBoi thats the quotient rule.... The product rule is $udv+vdu$

Comment: Can you explain the transition from $3rd \to 4th$ step?

Comment: @DatBoi the first term is the same... In the second term, I wrote $-\frac{du}{2(u^\frac32)}$ as $d(\frac{1}{u^\frac12})$

Comment: Understood. But applying your idea brings it to the form $\int vdu+udv=\int d(uv)$ rather than to the form $\int d(u/v)$

Comment: @DatBoi Yes... And you will find that this way is more efficient than $d(u/v)$. That is what I wanted to convey from the very beginning

Comment: @DatBoi You will gradually feel that thinking about the product rule is easier than that of the quotient rule. If you are a regular viewer of the blackpenredpen YouTube channel, you will naturally develop the intuition behind this.

Answer (score 0):

If you suppose the result is of the form
$$
\int\frac{kx+1}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{3/2}}dx=\frac{f(x)}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{1/2}}
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{1/2}}=\frac{kx+1}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{3/2}}
$$
expanding the LHS
$$
\frac{f'(x)(x^2+2kx+1)-(x+k)f(x)}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{3/2}}
$$
Supposing $f(x)=\alpha x+\beta$ we have
$$
\frac{(kx+1)\alpha-(x+k)\beta}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{3/2}}
$$
so we have to choose $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0,$ eventually
$$
\int\frac{kx+1}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{3/2}}dx=\frac{x}{(x^2+2kx+1)^{1/2}}+C
$$