# Integrals of the form $\int{d(\frac{u}{v})}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826874/734160), I wanted to devise a method to solve integrals of the form $\int{d(\frac{u}{v})}$

I was advised to manipulate it into the form [$\int udv+vdu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826901/734160) by one of the users (evident in the comments as well)

However, I stumbled upon a similar question again where it doesnt work:

$$\int{\frac{5x^8+7x^6}{(x^2+1+2x^7)^2}}dx$$

So getting back to a more basic arguement:

As the integral evaluates to $u/v$ where $u=-(x^2+1)$ and $v=2(2x^7+x^2+1)$ So the integral must be $\int{d(u/v)}=u/v$. So it must be possible to manipulate the original integral into the required form-$\int{d(u/v)}$. How do I do that?

Comment: Your example is of the form $\int\tfrac{U}{V}dx$, which in general doesn't reduce in a nontrivial way to $d\int\tfrac{u}{v}$.

Comment: @J.G. The integral evaluates to $-\dfrac{x^2+1}{2\left(2x^7+x^2+1\right)}$ which is of the form $\frac{u}{v}$. I also don't understand what nontrivial means in this context

Comment: What I mean is you don't always get that lucky. Sometimes the best you can hope for is the "[mathematician's answer](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MathematiciansAnswer)" $u=\int\tfrac{U}{V}dx,\,v=1$.

Comment: I do not see your problem ... by the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
∫ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\left(\frac uv\right)(x) \,\mathrm d x = \frac uv + C
$$
or perhaps I did not understand your notation?

Comment: @LL3.14 The problem is quite simple- reversing the integral back to the derivative of quotient form. And yes, the question is how to convert it to $d(u/v)$

Comment: Can you explicit what is $u$, $v$ here? And Where do you see $∫ d(u/v)$? For me $∫ d(u/v)$ means $∫ (u/v)'(x)\,\mathrm d x$. Right ?

Comment: The derivative as evident is of the form $u/v$, where $u=-(x^2+1)$ and $v=2(2x^7+x^2+1)$ So the integral must be $\int{d(u/v)}=u/v$. So It must be possible to manipulate it so. And thats exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: @DatBoi What if the problem were $\int\frac1xdx$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by what @Buraian put, but it is clear that:
$$\int d\left(\frac uv\right)=\frac uv+C$$
now:
$$\left(\frac uv\right)'=\frac{uv'}{v^2}-\frac{u'}{v}$$
so one way you could try and use this would be if, say:
$$I=\int\frac{uv'}{v^2}dx=\int\left[\left(\frac uv\right)'+\frac {u'}v\right]dx$$
if both of these were more trivial that your original integrals, however you would need to recognise the functions :/. Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: This method is genius. I tried it for some integrals and this works astonishingly well for every single one of them. And the process involves basic integrals with no effort required

Comment: Thanks! glad I could help

Comment: I suggest posting an answer showcasing some examples of this technique :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Factor $x^7$ from denominator:

$$ \int \frac{(5x^{-6} + 7 x^{-8} ) dx}{ (x^{-5} + x^{-7} + 2)^2}$$

Now simply put :

$$ x^{-5} + x^{-7} + 2 = u$$

Done!

Comment: Indeed. I want to focus more on the aspect of solving it in a generalized form of $u/v$

Answer (score 0):

In the notation my comment introduced, the case $V=w^2$ is always a hint to try $v=w$. For example, the given problem's obvious Ansatz takes polynomial $u$ and $v=2x^7+x^2+1$. The $x\to\infty$ asymptotic behaviour is for the integrand and its antiderivative to respectively go as $\tfrac54x^{-6},\,-\tfrac14x^{-5}$, so $u$ should be of the form $-\tfrac12x^2+ax+b$. You can find $a,\,b$ by solving simultaneous equations. As you've noted, we get $a=0,\,b=-\tfrac12$.

Comment: I have no idea about asymptotic behaviours. Can you explain it elementarily?

Comment: @DatBoi You could deduce the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Degree) another way. Without asymptotic behaviour, you'll need to find the $x^2$ coefficient from simultaneous equations too.

Comment: Im clearly confused! How do I compare the factors and check for their co prime nature? It would be really helpful if you can help me solve a particular example(possibly this one)