# $\int\frac{a^4-x^4}{(x^4+a^2x^2+a^4)^{3/2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{a^4-x^4}{(x^4+a^2x^2+a^4)^{3/2}} dx$$

I have tried rewriting $a^4-x^4$ as $x^4+a^2x^2+a^4-(2a^4+a^2x^2)$ and $x^4+a^2x^2+a^4$ as $(x^2+a^2+ax)^\frac{3}{2}(x^2+a^2-ax)^\frac{3}{2}$ which on breaking into partial fractions gives $$\int (x^4+a^2x^2+a^4)^{-1/2} +\int\frac{a^2(2a^2+x^2)}{(x^2+a^2+ax)^\frac{3}{2}(x^2+a^2-ax)^\frac{3}{2}}$$ Then I took $\frac{x}{a}$ as one variable $y$ but I didn't get much from this.

(Also I tried inputting this into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%28a%5E4-x%5E4%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Ba%5E2x%5E2%2Ba%5E4%29%5E%283%2F2%29) but for some reason it can't do it, no idea what I'm doing wrong)

Comment: Is there a reason you expect this to have a nice formula?

Comment: algebra-precalculus.....

Comment: @Ninad Munshi nothing other than it's more likely I am not able to reach an answer instead of my book making a mistake. Wolfram Alpha didn't give an answer but it also doesn't say anything like, it _can't_ give an answer so I was unsure of what the problem was. It would be great if I could get some confirmation and save my time

Comment: [Wolfram agrees with @NinadMunshi 's answer](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/0d0d5e34-146b-4ac3-bc4c-73b2b9222eec)

Comment: @Datboi thanks, any idea why it doesn't work here?https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28a%5E4-x%5E4%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Ba%5E2x%5E2%2Ba%5E4%29%5E%283%2F2%29+dx

Comment: @l1mbo no idea, didn't work with any of the refined queries as well. Someone with WA pro may try it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $x^3$

$$I = \int \frac{\frac{a^4}{x^3}-x}{\left(x^2+a^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\:dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d\left(x^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}\right)}{\left(x^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}+a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}+a^2}}+C$$

$$\implies \boxed{I = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+a^2x^2+a^4}}+C}$$

Comment: I am more lazy than you are ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

We could even do it without integration.
$$I=\int\frac{a^4-x^4}{(x^4+a^2x^2+a^4)^{3/2}} dx=\frac 1a \int \frac{1-y^4}{(y^4+y^2+1)^{3/2}} dy$$ Now, because of the power in denominator, assume that
$$\int \frac{1-y^4}{(y^4+y^2+1)^{3/2}} dy=\frac {P_n(y)}{(y^4+y^2+1)^{1/2}}$$ Differentiate both sides and simplify to get
$$1-y^4=\left(y^4+y^2+1\right) P_n'(y)-\left(2 y^3+y\right) P(y)$$ Comparing the degrees on both sides it is clear that $n=1$. So make $P_1(y)=\alpha+\beta y$  and replace
$$1-y^4=\beta -\alpha  y-2 \alpha  y^3-\beta  y^4$$ then $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$

Comment: Really unique approach for even a simple problem, this is the extra benefit of asking questions on MSE

Comment: @l1mbo [here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3852849/734160) a more formal way to show it the way @ ClaudeLeibovici did